# Find the generators of a complete intersection maximal ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ideals, complete-intersection

Let $k$ be a field (not necessarily algebraically closed), define the $k$-algebra
$$
B:=k[x_{0}, x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}]_{(F_{2}F_{3})}
$$
(degree 0 part of the localization), it's the coordinate ring of the affine variety $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}_{k}^{3}$ defined by $F_{2}F_{3}\neq 0$, where $F_{2}, F_{3}$ are homogeneous irreducible of degree $4, 8$ respectively.

Assume the point $y=(0, 0, 1, 1)$ lies in $Y$, and its maximal ideal $M$ in $B$ is a complete intersection (generated by 3 elements), can we conclude that the elements 
$$
b_1=\frac{x_0^{12}}{F_{2}F_{3}}, b_2=\frac{x_1^{12}}{F_{2}F_{3}}, b_3=\frac{(x_2-x_3)^{12}}{F_{2}F_{3}}
$$
generates $M$? If not, how can we find its generators? Is there a general way to find the generators of a complete intersection ideal?

Remark: I want to find the explicit generators of the ideal $M$ in Claim 3 of N. M. Kumar's 1985 paper 'Stably free modules', in the case $p=2$.

Comment: That seems almost certainly false.  The maximal ideal is generated by $(Lx_3^{11})/(F_2F_3)$ for $L=x_0$, resp. $L=x_1$, $L=x_2-x_3$.

Comment: Aha, the elements you give seems true, I will work out the detail.

Comment: @Jason Starr I don't think the element $b_1$ above can be generated by the 3 elements you gave.

Comment: You are correct.  What I should have written is that, for the localization of $B$ at the maximal ideal, the maximal ideal of the local ring is generated by the images of the elements $(Lx_3^{11})/(F_2F_3)$.  In fact, they already generate the maximal ideal after inverting the element $x_3^{12}/(F_2F_3)$ that is contained in the complement of the maximal ideal.  At any rate, since your elements *do not* generate the maximal ideal even in the local ring, they do not generate the maximal ideal in $B$.

Comment: @Jason Starr: I understand, thanks a lot for your comments!